# How to replace a string in a file without changing encoding

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace a single character '°' with '?' in an [edf](https://www.edfplus.info/specs/edf.html) file with binary encoding.([File](https://github.com/warren-manuel/sleep-edf/tree/main/Files)) I need to change all occurances of it in the first line.

I cannot open it without specifying read binary. (The following fails with UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 3008: invalid start byte)

```
with open('heartbeat-baseline-700001.edf') as fin:
lines = fin.readlines()
```

I ended up trying to replace it via this code

```
with open("heartbeat-baseline-700001.edf", "rb") as text_file:
lines = text_file.readlines()
lines[1] = lines[1].replace(str.encode('°'), str.encode('?'))
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    with open('heartbeat-baseline-700001_python.edf', 'wb') as fout:
        fout.write(line)
```

What I end up with is a file that is exponentially smaller (7KB vs 79MB) and does not work.

What seems to be the issue with this code? Is there a simpler way to replace the character?

Comment: In your `for` loop, you are just **overwriting** a single line to the file, not (i assume) appending. Try `ab` instead of `wb`? Or exchange `for` and `with open` so that the `fout.write` is done while the file is open

Comment: Put the `for` loop inside the second `with` statement, not the other way around

Comment: Providing an actual EDF file with the problem would enable better guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The file is not 100% encoded text, so that's why it must be opened as binary.  You can't use `readlines()` as the spec indicates space-padded fields in the ASCII fields, i.e., no newlines.  Use `'r+b'` to open for read/update of the binary file, `seek()` to the offset of the byte you want to replace, and `write(b'?')` the question mark byte.

Example:

```py
# Create a small example file
with open("heartbeat-baseline-700001.edf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b'ABCDEFG')

# Change a byte
with open("heartbeat-baseline-700001.edf", "r+b") as f:
    f.seek(3)     # offset of "D"
    f.write(b'?') # change to "?"

# read and display
with open("heartbeat-baseline-700001.edf", "rb") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
b'ABC?EFG'
```

Another issue is the `'°'` character.  It's not an ASCII character which violates the spec (likely why you are replacing it), but what encoding is it using? It's probably ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252...both of which encode as the byte `b'\xb0'`. but it could be UTF-8 which encodes as the **two** bytes `b'\xc2\xb0'`.  Assuming the former, that byte could occur in any of the data record *integer* fields as well, so be careful to replace the correct byte.  The UTF-8 pair could occur in the data fields as well, but less likely.

If you **know** the bad character is byte `b'\xb0'` and it occurs in the header before any data record entries, you could read the whole file, make a **single** replacement, and write the whole file back:

```py
# read the whole file as binary
with open('heartbeat-baseline-700001.edf', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

# replace the 1st 0xb0 byte found
data = data.replace(b'\xb0', b'?', 1)

# write the whole file back
with open('heartbeat-baseline-700001.edf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Mark ! I'll be quite honest I'm a little overwhelmed with the encodings. I had to get permission to deidentify the records but you can find the deidentified file [here] (https://file.io/LcdyHq5NJ4cJ) What I do know is that the issue is with the header containing invalid characters at positions 3009/3017/3025 hence why I tried to update only the first line.

Comment: @WarrenManuel The bad bytes are value B0 like in the last example.  They are the first 3 B0 in the file, so you could use my last example but use 3 instead of 1 for the number to replace.  You could even use `data = data.replace(b'\xb0\x20\x20\x20', b'degC', 3)` to replace the degree symbol and the space padding (B0 20 20 20) with `degC` if you wanted a more accurate unit than a question mark 

Comment: Yes ! This actually worked. But if you could indulge once more. When I used  `str.encode('°')` the output was **b'\xc2\xb0'** and not b'\xb0' as your solution pointed out. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: `str.encode()` defaults to UTF8  encoding. Use `'°'.encode('latin1')` instead

Answer (score 2):

When you're opening the file using 'wb' and writing, you are overwriting the entire file each time through. What you want is to control the write/read head, move it where you need it, and overwrite where needed.

A few changes will need to be made. First you need a reference to the open file. `with open()` I didn't test, so idk if it works - I'm sure it does. You can use the plain `file = open('filepath')` or test `with open()`, but you need the reference and if you don't use `with open()`, you'll need to explicitly call file.close() when you're done. Second you want to open the file using rb+, not wb so that you're not overwriting the file each time. Finally, you want to control the read/write head so that you can position it correctly for your reads/writes/overwrites.

```
def main():
    file = open("test.txt", "rb")
    filePos = 0
    
    while True:
        # Read the file character by character
        char = file.read(1)
        # When we find the char we want, break the loop and save the read/write head position.
        # Since we're in binary, we need to decode to get it to proper format for comparison (or encode the char)
        if char.decode('ascii') == "*":
            filePos = file.tell()
            break
        # If no more characters, we're at the end of the file. Break the loop and end the program.
        elif not char:
            break
       
    
    # Resolve open/unneeded file pointers.
    file.close()
    
    # Open the file in rb+ mode for writing without overwriting.
    fileWrite = open("test.txt", 'rb+')
    
    # Move the read/write head to the location we found our char at. 
    fileWrite.seek(filePos - 1)
    
    # Overwrite our char.
    fileWrite.write(bytes("?", "ascii"))
    
    # Close the file
    fileWrite.close()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
**Starting file contents:** This is old data with this * weird symbol that needs replacing.

**Completed file contents:** This is old data with this ? weird symbol that needs replacing.
```